Expressing a 2nd linear order ODE in the form [A(x)y'+B(x)y]'=0
I am trying to figure out when a second order Linear ODE of the form :
$$P(x)y''+Q(x)y'+R(x)y=0$$ (P,Q,R are differentiable functions)
can be expressed in the following form :
$$[A(x)y'+B(x)y]'=0$$
I have shown that :
$$[A(x)y'+B(x)y]'=0 <=> A(x)y''+(A'(x)+B(x))y'+B'(x)y=0$$
and i have also shown that the given ODE can be written in the form:
$$[P(x)y'+(Q(x)-P'(x))y']'+[R(x)-Q'(x)+P''(x)]y=0$$
(you can easily confirm the above just by doing the calculations).Therefore if: $$R(x)-Q'(x)+P''(x)=0$$
it is obvious that it can be written in that form and it is also trivial to find functions A,B.Does the inverse of the above statement also hold true?
If a 2nd order Linear ODE can be written in the form: $$[A(x)y'+B(x)y]'=0$$ does that mean that $R(x)-Q'(x)+P''(x)=0$?

$(A y' + B y)' = A y'' + (A' + B) y' + B' y$, so you should have $P = A$, $Q = A' + B$ and $R  = B'$.  Then $R - Q' + P'' = B' - (A'' + B') + A'' = 0$.

Why should i have P=A etc. couldn't  P=cA ,Q=c(A'+B) etc. also be true ? Is there any way to prove that given two equivalent 2nd order Linear ODE there is a certain relation between their coefficients?

I understood "can be expressed in the following form" to mean "is the same differential equation (up to simplification)".  Of course it would also work for a nonzero constant multiple of the differential equation.  On the other hand, it would not work  if you multiplied the equation by a non-constant function.  Thus $e^x P y'' + e^x Q y' + e^x R y  = 0$ is equivalent to $P y'' + Q y' + R y = 0$ (i.e. they have the same solutions), but it would not satisfy $(e^x R) - (e^x Q)' + (e^x P)'' = 0$.
